# I am not sure if my data are spatially autocorrelated or not.

Tags: autocorrelation, sas, spatial, variogram

I have been trying to figure out if my data are spatially autocorrelated by generating semivariogram of the residuals. I do not get the shape similar to any variogram (spherical, exponential or gaussian). I have attached the picture of the shapes that I have for 5 variables. I would be very thankful if you could provide me an insight on how to interpret any information from the semivariograms.

[image: CFP number]
[image: CFP area]
[image: Drainage density]
[image: CFP length to drainage area ratio]
[image: CFP length]